# Changing keras backend from tensorflow cpu to gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Is there a difference (in code) between keras tensorflow-cpu backend and tensorflow-gpu backend? If I want to change tensorflow from cpu to gpu, what code do I need to add or what environmental variables do I need to set?

From [keras link](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#multi-gpu-and-distributed-training) I know that I can use `tf.devices` - something like the code below. But what if I want the whole code, not just some part to run on GPU?

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 20, 64))
    y = LSTM(32)(x)  # all ops in the LSTM layer will live on GPU:0

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 20, 64))
    y = LSTM(32)(x)  # all ops in the LSTM layer will live on CPU:0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just uninstall `tensorflow-cpu` (`pip uninstall tensorflow`) and install `tensorflow-gpu` (`pip install tensorflow-gpu`). Now tensorflow will always use your gpu(s).

If you only want to use cpu in tensorflow-gpu set the environmental variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` so that the gpus are invisible. Before loading tensorflow do this in your script:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
import tensorflow
```